# Error with a predicate in std::remove_if

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I basically have an `std::deque` of objects, and I want to remove some of these objets according a condition on a given member variable of the objects, so that I use a predicate, but I have errors that I don't really understand.

I am using `g++` with the `-std=c++11` for STL reasons (shared pointers) but I was trying to work this out on windows with MVS with non `c++11` code, so that I am looking for a non `c++11` solution, without lamdas etc

The code is :

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout and std::endl
#include <cstdio> // for getchar()
#include <memory> // for std::shared_ptr
#include <deque> // for std::deque
#include <algorithm> // for std::earse and std::remove_if

class A
{
    private:
        int _i;
        double _d;
    public:
        A(int i, double d)
        {
            _i = i;
            _d = d;
        }
        int geti()const
        {
            return _i;
        }
        double getValueOnWhichToCheck()const
        {
            return _d;
        }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_shared_ptr;
typedef std::deque<A_shared_ptr> list_type;

void PrintDeque(list_type & dq)
{
    if (0 ==  dq.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Empty deque." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < dq.size() ; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << i+1 << "\t" << dq[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    public:
        double getThreshold() // Non constant for a reason as in real code it isn't
        {
            return 24.987; // comes from a calculation not needed here so I return a constant.
        }
        bool Predicate(A_shared_ptr & a)
        {
            return a->getValueOnWhichToCheck() >= getThreshold();
        }
        void DoStuff()
        {
            A_shared_ptr pT1 = std::make_shared<A>(A(2,      -6.899987));
            A_shared_ptr pT2 = std::make_shared<A>(A(876,    889.878762));
            A_shared_ptr pT3 = std::make_shared<A>(A(-24,    48.98924));
            A_shared_ptr pT4 = std::make_shared<A>(A(78,     -6654.98980));
            A_shared_ptr pT5 = std::make_shared<A>(A(6752,   3.141594209));
            list_type dq = {pT1,pT2,pT3,pT4,pT5};
            PrintDeque(dq);
            bool (B::*PtrToPredicate)(A_shared_ptr &) = &B::Predicate;
            dq.erase(std::remove_if(dq.begin(), dq.end(), PtrToPredicate),dq.end());
            PrintDeque(dq);
        }
};

int main()
{
    B * pB = new B();
    pB->DoStuff();
    getchar();
}
```

and the output of `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` is :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::shared_ptr<A>&, std::shared_ptr<A>*>; _Predicate = bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:866:20:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::shared_ptr<A>&, std::shared_ptr<A>*>; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:936:30:   required from ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = std::_Deque_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::shared_ptr<A>&, std::shared_ptr<A>*>; _Predicate = bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)]’
main.cpp:67:73:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)>::_M_pred (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)>::_M_pred) (...)’
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
                              ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fan of function pointers, but using lambda's this seems to compile... https://ideone.com/0StRcw

```
        dq.erase(std::remove_if(dq.begin(), dq.end(), [this](const std::shared_ptr<A>& a) {
            return a->getValueOnWhichToCheck() >= getThreshold();
        }),dq.end());
```

Or without lambdas..

```
        auto predicateToUse = std::bind(&B::Predicate, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        dq.erase(std::remove_if(dq.begin(), dq.end(), predicateToUse), dq.end());
```

Update no auto:

```
dq.erase(std::remove_if(dq.begin(), dq.end(), std::bind(&B::Predicate, this, std::placeholders::_1)), dq.end());
```

Comment: I know but I'm not allowing (in the solution I am working in) to use lambda's... :-( Question updated

Comment: Well you have a deque of shared pointers and your predicate takes a reference to an object, so you'll have to change it to take a reference to a shared_ptr

Comment: If you can't use lambda's, could you use struct-based functors?

Comment: Yes for sure. Tried `bool Predicate(A_shared_ptr a)` but I have `cannot convert ‘bool (B::*)(A_shared_ptr) {aka bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>)}’ to ‘bool (B::*)(A_shared_ptr&) {aka bool (B::*)(std::shared_ptr<A>&)}’ in initialization
             bool (B::*PtrToPredicate)(A_shared_ptr &) = &B::Predicate;` issues...

Comment: The trouble is, as @NathanOliver pointed out, you can't use a non-static member function pointer with remove_if. I updated my answer to include a workaround of sorts with std::bind, but lambdas are clearer imo.

Comment: I am not even allowed to use auto (thx to the fact that I ship to old solaris platforms as well...)

Comment: It works indeed, I just need to figure out the type of `predicateToUse` to validate

Comment: std::bind doesn't have a defined type so you can't get it without `auto`. I updated my response... basically just never name it if you can't use auto, and move the bind into the remove_if

Comment: Yes, but I had to use it at several places, so I thought declaring it, but it is not a big deal. Finally I used `boost::bind` which is perfectly kosher in the library I work in. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to use a non static member function pointer with `remove_if`.  `remove_if` requires a normal function pointer, static member function pointer or a function object.  The reason it cannot use a member function pointer is because it needs an instance of the class in order to be able to call the function and you cannot wrap that into the call

You are either need to make `Predicate` `static`, create a function object and pass an instance of that, or use a lambda in the call site.

Comment: Can I use `bind` somehow or ? (I am really not an expert, sorry)

Comment: @user10000100_u Yes you could use bind but that is a C++11 feature and if you are going to use C++11 you should just use a lambda.

Comment: I finally used `boost::bind` which is "allowed". Thx anyway !